# При создании БД выдает ошибку в консоли на чтение файла C++

Tags: c++, c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <clocale>
#define FNAME_I "C:\Qt\\bd1.dat"
#define FNAME_R "C:\Qt\\bd2.dat"



int proverka_file(char *fname, const char *);
void dozapolneniye(char *fname);
void table();
void table2();
void prosmotrbd1(char *fname);
void prosmotrbd2(char *fname);
void findname(char *fname1, char *fname2);
void sort_name(char *fname);
void sort_voz_count_prop(char *fname);

const char PR_R[] = "r";
const char PR_S[] = "r+";
const char PR_W[] = "w";
const char PR_A[] = "a";

typedef struct
{
    char tip[10];
    char num[7];
    int kolich;
    int chas;
    int kilom;
}str;

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int var;
    char otv;
    char fname_i[15] = FNAME_I;
    char fname_r[15] = FNAME_R;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    for (;;)
    {
        cout << "\n    Shto sdelat:" << endl;
        cout << "  1 - sozdaniye bazi dannih" << endl;
        cout << "  2 - dobavleniye novih zapisey" << endl;
        cout << "  3 - sortirovka po tipu samoleta" << endl;
        cout << "  4 - sortirovka po konechnomu naletu" << endl;
        cout << "  5 - poisk nomera borta" << endl;
        cout << "  6 - prosmotr bazi dannih" << endl;
        cout << "  7 - prosmotr bazi dannih po poisku" << endl;
        cout << "  8 - zaversheniye" << endl;
        cout << "  Vvedite shto nuzhno sdelat ->";
        cin >> var;
        switch (var)
        {
        default:break;
        case 1: if (proverka_file(fname_i, PR_R))
        {
                    cout << " Baza dannih " << fname_i;
                    cout << " uzhe sozdana." << endl;
                    cout << " Sozdat noviy fail? [Y/N] ";
                    cin >> otv;
                    cin.get();
                    if (otv == 'Y' || otv == 'y' || otv == 'Н' || otv == 'н')
                    {
                        cout << " Vvedite novoe imya: ";
                        cin >> fname_i;
                    }
                    else break;
        }
                if (!proverka_file(fname_i, PR_W))
                {
                    cout << "\n Oshibka otkritiya faila dlya zapisi" << endl;
                    cout << " Dlya prodolzheniya nazhmite Enter->"; getchar();
                    break;
                }
                cout << " Sozdaem bazu " << fname_i << endl;
                dozapolneniye(fname_i);
                cout << "\n Sozdaniye faila zakoncheno." << endl;
                if (proverka_file(fname_i, PR_R))
                    cout << " Baza dannih gotova k rabote" << endl;
                else cout << "\n Baza ne sozdana" << endl;
                cout << " Dlya prodolzheniya nazhmite Enter->"; getchar();
                break;
        case 2: if (proverka_file(fname_i, PR_R))
        {
                    cout << " Baza dannih poletov " << fname_i;
                    cout << " bila sozdana ranshe." << endl;
                    cout << " Dovavit noviye zapisi? [Y/N] ";
                    cin >> otv;
                    cin.get();
                    if (otv == 'N' || otv == 'n' || otv == 'Т' || otv == 'т')
                    {
                        cout << " Vvedite imya drugoy bazi: ";
                        cin >> fname_i;
                        if (!proverka_file(fname_i, PR_R))
                        {
                            cout << " Takaya baza dannih ne sozdavalas" << endl;
                            cout << " Dlya prodolzheniya nazhmite Enter->"; getchar();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
        }
                cout << " Dobavlyaem zapisi v fail" << fname_i << endl;
                dozapolneniye(fname_i);
                cout << "\n Izmeneniye faila zakoncheno.";
                cout << " Dlya prodolzheniya nazhmite Enter->"; getchar();
                break;
        case 3: if (!proverka_file(fname_i, PR_S))
        {
                    cout << "\n Oshibka otkritiya faila dlya chteniya i zapisi" << endl;
                    cout << " Dlya prodolzheniya nazhmite Enter->"; getchar();
                    break;
        }
                sort_name(fname_i);
                cout << "\n Sortirovka zakonchena.";
                cout << " Dlya prodolzheniya nazhmite Enter->"; getchar();
                break;
        case 4: if (!proverka_file(fname_i, PR_S))
        {
                    cout << "\n Oshibka otkritiya faila dlya chteniya i zapisi" << endl;
                    cout << " Dlya prodolzheniya nazhmite Enter->"; getchar();
                    break;
        }
                sort_voz_count_prop(fname_i);
                cout << "\n Sortirovka zakonchena.";
                cout << " Dlya prodolzheniya nazhmite Enter->"; getchar();
                break;
        case 5: if (!proverka_file(fname_i, PR_R))
        {
                    cout << "\n Oshibka otkritiya faila dlya chteniya" << endl;
                    cout << " Dlya prodolzheniya nazhmite Enter->"; getchar();
                    break;
        }
                if (!proverka_file(fname_r, PR_W))
                {
                    cout << "\n Oshibka otkritiya faila dlya zapisi" << endl;
                    cout << " Dlya prodolzheniya nazhmite Enter->"; getchar();
                    break;
                }
                findname(fname_i, fname_r);
                cout << "\n Poisk samoleta po nomeru borta.";
                cout << " Dlya prodolzheniya nazhmite Enter->"; getchar();
                break;
        case 6: if (!proverka_file(fname_i, PR_R))
        {
                    cout << "\n Oshibka otkritiya faila dlya chteniya" << endl;
                    cout << " Dlya prodolzheniya nazhmite Enter->"; getchar();
                    break;
        }
                prosmotrbd1(fname_i);
                cout << "\n Dlya prodolzheniya nazhmite Enter->"; getchar();
                break;
        case 7: if (!proverka_file(fname_r, PR_R))
        {
                    cout << "\n Oshibka otkritiya faila dlya chteniya" << endl;
                    cout << " Dlya prodolzheniya nazhmite Enter->"; getchar();
                    break;
        }
                prosmotrbd2(fname_r);
                cout << "\n Dlya prodolzheniya nazhmite Enter->"; getchar();
                break;
        case 8: return 0;
        }
    }
}

void dozapolneniye(char *fname)
{
    char otv;
    str s;
    FILE *baza;
    baza = fopen(fname, PR_A);
    rewind(baza);
    do
    {
        cout << "\n Tip samoleta? ";
        cin >> s.tip;
        cout << " Nomer borta? ";
        cin >> s.num;
        cout << " Kolichestvo reisov? ";
        cin >> s.kolich;
        cout << " Nalet v chas? ";
        cin >> s.chas;
        cout << " Nalet v kilometrah? ";
        cin >> s.kilom;
        fwrite(&s, sizeof(s), 1, baza);
        cout << "\n Prodolzhit?[Y/N]";
        cin >> otv;
        cin.get();
    } while (otv == 'Y' || otv == 'y' || otv == 'Н' || otv == 'н');
    fclose(baza);
}

void table()
{
    int i;
    cout << "\n";
    for (i = 1; i <= 71; i++)
        cout << "-";
    cout << endl;
    cout << "| Tip samoleta  |" << "  Num borta  |" << "  Kolvo reisov  |"
        << "  Nalet/chas  |" << "Nalet/km|" << endl;
    for (i = 1; i <= 63; i++)
        cout << "-";
}

void table2()
{
    int i;
    cout << "\n";
    for (i = 1; i <= 71; i++)
        cout << "-";
    cout << endl;
    cout << "| Tip samoleta  |" << "  Num borta  |" << "  Kolvo reisov  |"
        << "  Nalet/chas  |" << "Nalet/km|" << endl;
    for (i = 1; i <= 65; i++)
        cout << "-";
}

void prosmotrbd1(char *fname)
{
    int i;
    str s;
    FILE *baza;
    baza = fopen(fname, PR_R);
    cout << "\n     Baza dannih poletov";
    table();
    rewind(baza);
    while (fread(&s, sizeof(s), 1, baza) > 0)
    {
        cout << "\n|";
        cout.width(20); cout << s.tip << "|";
        cout.width(9); cout << s.num << "|";
        cout.width(9); cout << s.kolich << "|";
        cout.width(9); cout << s.chas << "|";
        cout.width(17);  cout << s.kilom << "|";
    }
    cout << "\n";
    for (i = 1; i <= 71; i++)
        cout << "-";
    fclose(baza);
}

void prosmotrbd2(char *fname)
{
    int i;
    str s;
    FILE *baza;
    baza = fopen(fname, PR_R);
    cout << "\n  Baza dannih poiska po tipu samoleta";
    table2();
    rewind(baza);
    while (fread(&s, sizeof(s), 1, baza) > 0)
    {
        cout << "\n|";
        cout.width(10); cout << s.tip << "|";
        cout.width(2); cout << s.num << "|";
        cout.width(3); cout << s.kolich << "|";
        cout.width(3); cout << s.chas << "|";
        cout.width(3);  cout << s.kilom << "|";
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (i = 1; i <= 65; i++)
        cout << "-";
    fclose(baza);
}

void findname(char *fname1, char *fname2)
{
    char num[7];
    str s;
    FILE *in, *out;
    in = fopen(fname1, PR_R);
    out = fopen(fname2, PR_W);
    cout << "\n Nomer borta dlya poiska? ";
    cin >> num;
    rewind(in);
    while (fread(&s, sizeof(s), 1, in) > 0)
    if (strncmp(s.num, num, 10) == 0)
        fwrite(&s, sizeof(s), 1, out);
    fclose(out);
    fclose(in);
}

void sort_name(char *fname)
{
    int i;
    int fl;
    str ppp, s;
    FILE *baza;
    baza = fopen(fname, PR_S);
    do{
        rewind(baza);
        fl = 0;
        for (i = 0; fread(&s, sizeof(s), 1, baza) > 0; i += sizeof(s), fseek(baza, i, SEEK_SET))
        if (fread(&ppp, sizeof(s), 1, baza) > 0)
        if (strncmp(s.tip, ppp.tip, 10) > 0)
        {
            fseek(baza, i, SEEK_SET);
            fwrite(&ppp, sizeof(s), 1, baza);
            fwrite(&s, sizeof(s), 1, baza);
            fl = 1;
        }
    } while (fl);
    fclose(baza);
}

void sort_voz_count_prop(char *fname)
{
    int i, fl;
    str ppp, s;
    FILE *baza;
    baza = fopen(fname, PR_S);
    do{
        rewind(baza);
        fl = 0;
        for (i = 0; fread(&s, sizeof(s), 1, baza) > 0; i += sizeof(s), fseek(baza, i, SEEK_SET))
        if (fread(&ppp, sizeof(s), 1, baza) > 0)
        if (s.kilom > ppp.kilom)
        {
            fseek(baza, i, SEEK_SET);
            fwrite(&ppp, sizeof(s), 1, baza);
            fwrite(&s, sizeof(s), 1, baza);
            fl = 1;
        }
    } while (fl);
    fclose(baza);
}

int proverka_file(char *fname, const char *pr)
{
    if ((fopen(fname, pr)) == NULL)
        return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Было бы неплохо, если бы вы еще предоставили текст самой ошибки, и номер строки, в которой происходит ошибка.

Comment: Oshibka otkritiya faila dlya zapisi - выводится в самой консоли. База данных создается, но для чтения или записи не открывается.

Comment: @Екатерина, у вас тут Qt и не пахнет. Весь код на чистом С++, а работа с файлами и вовсе на С. Думаю эти тэги будут уместнее

Comment: а права-то на работу каталоге есть???

Comment: вот в `proverka_file` файл открывается, а закрывать кто его будет?

Comment: Кстати, а имена файлов в макросах заданы не совсем верно `#define FNAME_I "C:\Qt\\bd1.dat"
#define FNAME_R "C:\Qt\\bd2.dat"` - слеши нужны двойные. Иначе это немного не та папка